# jQuery - sort li

Tags: jquery, sorting

I dont know why but this code is not sorting my li's properly. They are changing order, but for example if they are like this 1, 5, 2, 9 then it is changing to 5, 2, 9, 1.

jQuery code:

```
var sorter_type=new Array("date_sort","price_sort","discount_sort","time_sort");
function sorting_by_filter(filter_id,field)
{
    var sort_type="";

    if($('#'+filter_id).attr("class")=="asc")
    {   
        $('#'+filter_id).removeClass("asc");
        $('#'+filter_id).addClass("desc");
        sort_type=" desending";
    }
    else
    {
        $('#'+filter_id).removeClass("desc");
        $('#'+filter_id).addClass("asc");
        sort_type="";
    }

    for(i=0;i<sorter_type.length;i++)
    {
        if(sorter_type[i]==filter_id)
        {
            $('#'+filter_id).parent().attr("class","");
            $('#'+filter_id).parent().addClass("clsTop_Menu_Act"+sort_type);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#"+sorter_type[i]).parent().attr("class","");
        }

    }

    var $sort = $('#'+filter_id);

    var $list = $('.clsDeal_Whole_Cont');
    var $listLi = $('li.clsDeal_Blk_Cont',$list);
    $listLi.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = parseInt($(a).attr(field));
        var keyB = parseInt($(b).attr(field));
        if($($sort).hasClass('asc')){
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
    $.each($listLi, function(index, row){
        $list.append(row);
    });
}
```

buttons code:

```
        <ul class="clearfix" id="filters">
      <li class="clsTop_Menu_Act"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="asc"     onclick="sorting_by_filter('date_sort','title')" id="date_sort">New</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sorting_by_filter('price_sort','price')" class="asc" id="price_sort">Price</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sorting_by_filter('discount_sort','discount')" class="asc" id="discount_sort">Discount</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sorting_by_filter('time_sort','time_left')" class="asc" id="time_sort" >Time Left</a></li>
</ul>
```

content which needs to be sorted:

```
<ul class="clsDeal_Whole_Cont clearfix">
     <li class="clsDeal_Blk_Cont" style="display:block" id="deal_1"  price="2" discount="50" time_left="1360363800">
     <li class="clsDeal_Blk_Cont" style="display:block" id="deal_10"  price="20" discount="45" time_left="1360363700">
     <li class="clsDeal_Blk_Cont" style="display:block" id="deal_5"  price="19" discount="80" time_left="1360363800">
</ul>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your code is only doing some sorting. You should split it in tinier functions that do specific jobs. Gonna be much clearer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you never return `-1` from your sort callback. Always only `1` or `0`, which btw, you are not returning correctly either.

If you are sorting in *ascending* order then you have to return `-1` (negative number) if `keyA` is smaller than `keyB`, `0` if they are equal or `+1` (positive number) if `keyA` is larger than `keyB`.

Example:

```
$listLi.sort(function(a, b){
    var keyA = parseInt($(a).attr(field), 10);
    var keyB = parseInt($(b).attr(field), 10);

    // sorts in descending order. The result will be
    // negative if keyA > keyB
    // 0        if keyA == keyB
    // positive if keyA < keyB

    var result = keyB - keyA;
    if ($sort.hasClass('asc') {
        // multiplying by -1 reverses the order
        result = result * (-1);
    }
    return result;
});
```

Learn more about sort callbacks by reading the [`Array#sort` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: unfortunatelly this doesnt work either, li's are still in random order. Anyway, thanks for link.

Answer (score 0):

As Felix Kling points out, your sort function isn't up to scratch. These are the conditions a valid sort must address, from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

- If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b.
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
- `compareFunction(a, b)` must always returns the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined

He's already posted a working sort function (and 1'uped my documentation link), so I'll just point you to a jQuery UI plugin for taking the work out of implementing this in the future: [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).